# Pitch angle from Onboard SDK seems to decrease with speed

Tags: dji-sdk

I am reading the pitch and speed from the onboard SDK and notice a surprising pattern.  Today I tested flying legs north-south, each time pushing the pitch to maximum down and holding it there until reaching the other end of my play area, when I released the control, pivoted around and repeated...   The attached image shows the pitch angle and speed.  What I don't understand is why the pitch angle seems to ease up as the speed increases?  Is that an artifact of acceleration corrupting the pitch angle or does the Matrice actually shallow up the pitch angle as the speed increases?

[image: Plot of Pitch and Velocity]

Answer (score 0):

The pitch angle will be more correlated with the acceleration measurements and not so much with speed. This is because as the speed of the UAV increases towards the requirement from flight computer, the acceleration is decreasing, until it should finally reach zero, which means that the speed is constant. However, in real world, because of the air resistance and other things the pitch angle is instead maintained at the level enough to counteract air resistance to prevent decceleration, and thus you see the pitch angle leveling in your graph as well. Try to plot pitch vs acceleration, but note that for the IMU acceleration at constant speed will in fact be zero.